# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: reactjs

I checked if I had unclosed tags, parens and curly braces. No issue there to me.

I set up my node and react environment and have localhost:3000 up and running. No issue here to me.

But I don't know where to look anymore. Any idea, please? Thanks for your help.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
            addLevel1Num1: 1,
            addLevel1Num2: 1,
            subLevel1Num1: 1,
            subLevel1Num2: 1,
            addLevel2Num1: 1,
            addLevel2Num2: 1,
            subLevel2Num1: 20,
            subLevel2Num2: 20,
            response: "",
            incorrect: false,
            score: 0,
                // scoreSubLevel1: 3
        };
    }
}


class ProblemAddLevel1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id="mainTitle">Welcome to the Review Math Game Area!</h1>
                <div id="problem" className={this.state.incorrect ? "incorrect" : ""}>
                {this.state.addLevel1Num1} + {this.state.addLevel1Num2} = <input onKeyPress={this.inputKeyPressAddLevel1} onChange={this.updateResponse} value={this.state.response} class="resizedTextBox"/>
                Score: {this.state.score} <button onClick={this.resetLineAddLevel1} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Line</button> <button onClick={this.resetFullGame} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Full Game</button>
                </div>
           </div>
        ); 
    }
}
```

.... similar code as above skipped.

```
render() {
    if (this.state.score < 3) {
        return <ProblemAddLevel1 />;
    }
    if (this.state.score < 6) {
        return <ProblemSubLevel1 />;
    }
    if (this.state.score < 9) {
        return <ProblemAddLevel2 />;
    }
    if (this.state.score < 15) {
        return <ProblemSubLevel1 />;
    }
    if (this.state.score === 15) {
        return <WinRace />;
    }
}
```

....

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <div>
        <App />
        <ProblemAddLevel1 />
        <ProblemSubLevel1 />
        <ProblemAddLevel2 />
        <ProblemSubLevel1 />
        <WinRace />
    </div>
), document.querySelector("#app"));
```

I get this error in the browser:

```
Failed to compile

./src/App.js
  Line 109:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  107 | 
  108 | 
> 109 | render() {
      |          ^
  110 |     if (this.state.score < 3) {
  111 |         return <ProblemAddLevel1 />;
  112 |     }

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

I REWORKED ON THIS ISSUE TODAY LOOKING FOR FIXES AND GOT SOMETHING ELSE:

APP.JS

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import './index.js';
import './index.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                addLevel1Num1: 1,
                addLevel1Num2: 1,
                subLevel1Num1: 1,
                subLevel1Num2: 1,
                addLevel2Num1: 1,
                addLevel2Num2: 1,
                subLevel2Num1: 20,
                subLevel2Num2: 20,
                response: "",
                incorrect: false,
                score: 0,
                // scoreSubLevel1: 3
            };
        }

    render() {
        if (this.state.score < 3) {
            return <ProblemAddLevel1 />;
        }
        if (this.state.score < 6) {
            return <ProblemSubLevel1 />;
        }
        if (this.state.score < 9) {
            return <ProblemAddLevel2 />;
        }
        if (this.state.score < 15) {
            return <ProblemSubLevel1 />;
        }
        if (this.state.score === 15) {
            return <WinRace />;
        }
    }
    default export App;
}


class ProblemAddLevel1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id="mainTitle">Welcome to the Review Math Game Area!</h1>
                <div id="problem" className={this.state.incorrect ? "incorrect" : ""}>
                {this.state.addLevel1Num1} + {this.state.addLevel1Num2} = <input onKeyPress={this.inputKeyPressAddLevel1} onChange={this.updateResponse} value={this.state.response} class="resizedTextBox"/>
                Score: {this.state.score} <button onClick={this.resetLineAddLevel1} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Line</button> <button onClick={this.resetFullGame} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Full Game</button>
                </div>
           </div>
        );
    }
}



class ProblemSubLevel1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <h1 id="mainTitle">Welcome to the Review Math Game Area!</h1>
            <div id="problem" className={this.state.incorrect ? "incorrect" : ""}>
            {this.state.subLevel1Num1} - {this.state.subLevel1Num2} = <input onKeyPress={this.inputKeyPressSubLevel1} onChange={this.updateResponse} value={this.state.response} class="resizedTextBox"/>
            Score: {this.state.score} <button onClick={this.resetLineSubLevel1} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Line</button> <button onClick={this.resetFullGame} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Full Game</button>
            <img id="green-leaf" src={'./green-leaf.svg'} />
            </div>
       </div>
       );
    }
}


class ProblemAddLevel2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id="mainTitle">Welcome to the Review Math Game Area!</h1>
                <div id="problem" className={this.state.incorrect ? "incorrect" : ""}>
                {this.state.addLevel2Num1} + {this.state.addLevel2Num2} = <input onKeyPress={this.inputKeyPressAddLevel2} onChange={this.updateResponse} value={this.state.response} class="resizedTextBox"/>
                Score: {this.state.score} <button onClick={this.resetLineAddLevel2} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Line</button> <button onClick={this.resetFullGame} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Full Game</button>
               <img id="green-leaf" src={'./green-leaf.svg'} />
               <img id="green-leaf" src={'./green-leaf.svg'} />
               </div>
           </div>
        );
    }
}


class ProblemSubLevel2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id="mainTitle">Welcome to the Review Math Game Area!</h1>
                <div id="problem" className={this.state.incorrect ? "incorrect" : ""}>
                {this.state.subLevel2Num1} - {this.state.subLevel2Num2} = <input onKeyPress={this.inputKeyPressSubLevel2} onChange={this.updateResponse} value={this.state.response} class="resizedTextBox"/>
                Score: {this.state.score} <button onClick={this.resetLineSubLevel2} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Line</button> <button onClick={this.resetFullGame} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Full Game</button>
                <img id="green-leaf" src={'./green-leaf.svg'} />
                <img id="green-leaf" src={'./green-leaf.svg'} />
                <img id="green-leaf" src={'./green-leaf.svg'} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class WinRace extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id="mainTitle">Well done! You won the Four Green Leaves Title!</h1>
                <div id="problem" className={this.state.incorrect ? "incorrect" : ""}>
                Score: {this.state.score}
                <img id="green-leaf" src={'./green-leaf.svg'} />
                <img id="green-leaf" src={'./green-leaf.svg'} />
                <img id="green-leaf" src={'./green-leaf.svg'} />
                <img id="green-leaf" src={'./green-leaf.svg'} />
                <h2 id="mainTitle">Come back to review your maths in a few days!</h2>
                <button onClick={this.resetFullGame} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Full Game</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


updateResponse = (event) => {
    this.setState({ response: event.target.value });
}

inputKeyPressAddLevel1 = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        const answer = parseInt(this.state.response);
        if (answer === this.state.addLevel1Num1 + this.state.addLevel1Num2) {
            this.setState(state => ({
                addLevel1Num1: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.score,
                addLevel1Num2: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.score,
                // subLevel1Num1: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.scoreSubLevel1,
                // subLevel1Num2: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.scoreSubLevel2,
                response: "",
                incorrect: false,
                score: state.score + 1
            }));
        } else {
            this.setState({
                 response: "",
                 incorrect: true
            });
        }
    }
}


inputKeyPressSubLevel1 = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        const answer = parseInt(this.state.response);
        if (answer === this.state.subLevel1Num1 - this.state.subLevel1Num2) {
            this.setState(state => ({
                subLevel1Num1: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.score,
                subLevel1Num2: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.score,
                response: "",
                incorrect: false,
                score: state.score + 1
            }));
        } else {
            this.setState({
                response: "",
                incorrect: true
            });
        }
    }
}


inputKeyPressAddLevel2 = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        const answer = parseInt(this.state.response);
        if (answer === this.state.addLevel2Num1 + this.state.addLevel2Num2) {
            this.setState(state => ({
                addLevel2Num1: (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)) * 2 + state.score,
                addLevel2Num2: (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)) * 2 + state.score,
                // subLevel1Num1: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.scoreSubLevel1,
                // subLevel1Num2: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.scoreSubLevel2,
                response: "",
                incorrect: false,
                score: state.score + 1
            }));
        } else {
            this.setState({
                response: "",
                incorrect: true
            });
        }
    }
}


inputKeyPressSubLevel2 = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        const answer = parseInt(this.state.response);
        if (answer === this.state.subLevel2Num1 - this.state.subLevel2Num2) {
            this.setState(state => ({
                subLevel2Num1: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.score,
                subLevel2Num2: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.score,
                response: "",
                incorrect: false,
                score: state.score + 1
            }));
        } else {
            this.setState({
                response: "",
                incorrect: true
            });
        }
    }
}


resetFullGame = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        addLevel1Num1: 1,
        addLevel1Num2: 1,
        subLevel1Num1: 1,
        subLevel1Num2: 1,
        addLevel2Num1: 1,
        addLevel2Num2: 1,
        subLevel2Num1: 1,
        subLevel2Num2: 1,
        response: "",
        incorrect: false,
        score: 0,
        // scoreSubLevel1: 0
    });
}


resetLineAddLevel1 = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        addLevel1Num1: 1,
        addLevel1Num2: 1,
        response: "",
        incorrect: false
    });
}


resetLineSubLevel1 = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        subLevel1Num1: 1,
        subLevel1Num2: 1,
        response: "",
        incorrect: false
    });
}


resetLineAddLevel2 = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        addLevel2Num1: 1,
        addLevel2Num2: 1,
        response: "",
        incorrect: false
    });
}


resetLineSubLevel1 = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        subLevel2Num1: 20,
        subLevel2Num2: 20,
        response: "",
        incorrect: false
    });
}


ReactDOM.render((
    <div>
        <App />
        <ProblemAddLevel1 />
        <ProblemSubLevel1 />
        <ProblemAddLevel2 />
        <ProblemSubLevel1 />
        <WinRace />
    </div>
), document.querySelector("#app"));
```

INDEX.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App.js';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: 
serviceWorker.unregister();

//export {default} from App;
```

Comment: And you get this error when exactly? When the page loads, when you click on a button etc?

Comment: This happens when the page loads. So I just see this error message.

Comment: At which line do you get the error? Can you share the whole error - normally you get information on which line the error is....

Comment: You are setting state in App component and using it in ProblemAddLevel1 component without passing the state?

Comment: Post your error

Comment: @timotom, i don't think that you can use App component's state in ProblemAddLevel1component. Also every react component class based component must implement the render method. Your App component doesn't have render method implementation.

Comment: Full error message added. Thanks for your input.

Comment: As I may understand, I will need to have my props from App component pass to ProblemAddLevel1 component.

Comment: @Pavan, If I don't use App, I cannot rely on function base only. Or are you saying that I would still need to add something in App to make it work?

Comment: There is a syntax error in `App`; please share the entire component.

Comment: @Jake Worth, I sent the whole code just in case. Thanks.

Comment: `default export App` must be at the top level. There too many issues there.

Comment: @Sulthan, By top level, you mean just below the import statements at the top? Thanks.

Comment: You are using `class` instead of `className`.

Comment: @Sulthan. Thanks but isn't "class App extends React.Component" standard React statement? I used className in the code as well i.e. in the class divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors I can see but the most obvious ones:

1. You cannot use `class` in React components. Use `className` instead. For example here:

   ```
   <button onClick={this.resetLineAddLevel1} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Line</button>
   ```
2. exports must be at the top-level. That means outside any `{` and `}` and they are written differently:

   ```
   default export App;
   ```

   should be

   ```
   export default App;
   ```
3. You have methods that don't return anything in some cases. Your methods should always return a component or at least `null`, e.g. here:

   ```
   render() {
       if (this.state.score < 3) {
           return <ProblemAddLevel1 />;
       }
       if (this.state.score < 6) {
           return <ProblemSubLevel1 />;
       }
       if (this.state.score < 9) {
           return <ProblemAddLevel2 />;
       }
       if (this.state.score < 15) {
           return <ProblemSubLevel1 />;
       }
       if (this.state.score === 15) {
           return <WinRace />;
       }

       // missing return
   }
   ```

4. Your event handlers, e.g. `updateResponse` are declared at top-level, not inside of any class but you are using `this` inside them.

In summary, I really recommend to go back a step and start with something more basic and ideally find a good editor (e.g. Webstorm) that will show you all the errors immediately.

Answer (score 0):

you need render a element. `<div></div>` by default

```
  render() {

        let finalComponent;
        if (this.state.score < 3) {
            finalComponent = <ProblemAddLevel1 />;
        }
        if (this.state.score < 6) {
           finalComponent = <ProblemSubLevel1 />;
        }
        if (this.state.score < 9) {
            finalComponent =  <ProblemAddLevel2 />;
        }
        if (this.state.score < 15) {
            finalComponent =  <ProblemSubLevel1 />;
        }
        if (this.state.score === 15) {
            return <WinRace />;
        }
       return(
            <div>{finalComponent}</div>
       );
 }
```

with the ifs youre not returnin nothing directly, if you want make a return you need do it in one sentence, you can do the return with anonym function returning the component

sorry for my bad english :c

Comment: Thanks Black Hole. This will certainly help me but i have other issues to fix in this code as well as per the comments.

Comment: This code is missing a `return` keyword before the divs.